# What does this list comprehension do?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

```py
dp = [[0 for x in range(m+1)] for x in range(n+1)]
```

Can someone explain this code what actually happens in this part of the code? I think this involves list comprehensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dp = [[0 for x in range(m+1)] for x in range(n+1)]
```

This is equivalent to

```
for x in range(n+1):
  for x in range(m+1):
    dp = 0
```

This will create a 2D array of size `(n + 1) x (m + 1)`. Suppose, n = 2, and m = 3. Then, the outer loop will run for 3 times, and for each time the outer loop runs, the inner loop will run 4 times. So, it will make a list ````` [0 0 0 0]```` (in the inner loop). Now, as the inner loop is executing thrice, there will be 3 lists `````[0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0]```, and they will altogether form a 3 x 4 matrix.

This can be better understood as

```
for x in range(3):
    for x in range(4):
        print(0, end = ' ')
    print()
```

The above snippet outputs

```
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically dp will be a 2D-Matrix of dimension(n+1,m+1).

1. `[0 for x in range(m+1)]` : this create a list of size `(m+1)` initialized with zeros.

   For example: if `m=2`, list will be `[0,0,0]`
2. `[[0 for x in range(m+1)] for x in range(n+1)]` : Now when we see the whole code 
   together, we will get a 2D list.

   For example, if `n=2`, dp will be `[[0,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0]]`